# How to customize list item menu on Sharepoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, menu-item

On SharePoint Online i'm trying to override list item menu.
On onpremise I implement javascript fuction

```
Custom_AddListMenuItems = function (m, ctx, url) {

    // ADD ITEMS ****************************
    CAMOpt(m, "Hello World", "alert('Hello World')", "");

    if (function_chained === undefined)
        return;
    return function_chained(m, ctx, url);
};
```

With this function on online. It goes in when I click on menu but parameter "m" is null so it doesn't customize menu.

I use this solution to add custom action and it works great but I need to remove standard menu and keep a complete custom.
https://sharepointmates.com/2017/06/30/custom-actions-using-csom-for-sharepoint-online/

How can I do this as in SP2013? I could hide menu lind I don't want with css but it's tricky.